# How to validate an iframe content with Required Field validator?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

```
<iframe id="editable">
    Some really boring text.
</iframe>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="editable" ErrorMessage="* The user name field is required." />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {
        var iframe = document.getElementById('editable');
        var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

        doc.body.innerHTML = iframe.textContent || iframe.innerHTML;

        // Make IFRAME editable
        if (doc.body.contentEditable) {
            doc.body.contentEditable = true;
        }
    }

</script>
```

It is showing this error while validating the Iframe with required field validator:

> Unable to find control id 'editable' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of 'RequiredFieldValidator2'